# JTextPane replace string in document

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I had `JTextPane` with content type HTML

```
JTextPane editor = new JTextPane();
editor.setContentType("text/html");
```

When user input "\" I want to be inputted "&#92" (code of "\"). How can I do it?

Comment: You can get the ASCII number value through `char`. \ is an escape character, so you'd have to double it up. If you input \\, it prints out just \.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When user input "\" I want to be inputted "&#92" (code of "\"). How can I do it?

Use a `DocumentFilter` to translate the string before it is entered into the `Document`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Implement a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information to get you started.

To override the replace(...) method you might do something like:

```
public void replace(final FilterBypass fb, final int offs, final int length, final String str, final AttributeSet a)
{
    if (str.equals("\"))
        super.replace(fb, ofs, length, "&#92", a);
    else
        super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
}
```